# Why does this lodash template throw a syntax error? It looks fine to me

Tags: javascript, templates, syntax-error, underscore.js, lodash

This template looks perfectly fine to me:

```
var renderFormElement = _.template([
    '<% if (input.hasOwnProperty("label")) { %>',
        '<label class="form__label" for="<%- input.key %>"> <%- input.label %> </label>',
    '<% } %>',
    '<% if (input.hasOwnProperty("options")) { %>',
        '<select name="<%- input.key %>" id="<%- input.key %>">',
            '<% _.forEach(input.options, function(option) { %>',
                '<option value=""><%- options %></option>',
            '<% }); %>',
        '</select>',
    '<% } elseif (input.hasOwnProperty("type")) { %>',
        '<input type="<%- input.type %>"/>',
    '<% } %>'
].join('\n'));
```

Yet it throws an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" exception. Am I going crazy here? Unfortunately I can't seem to find a proper linter/syntax highlighter for my editor (Sublime Text), and pasting this code in an online validator gives me the exact same error.

[image]

Comment: Read [ask], follow the steps to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example. If you still have a problem, post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `elseif` with `else if`..